# Писал код по книге Эла Свейгарта "Учим Пайтон делая крутые игры" игра ловкач и код запускается но не реагирует

Tags: python

```
import pygame, random,sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH= 600
WINDOWHEIGHT =600
TEXTCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60
BADDIEMINSIZE = 10
BADDDIEMAXSIZE = 40
BADIIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 6
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
        return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)


pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ловкач')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)


font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)

gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('Fluffing-a-Duck.mp3')

playerImage = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')

windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)
drawText('Ловкач', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Нажмите клавишу для начала игры', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 5) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

topScore = 0
while True:
    baddies = []

score = 0
playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
baddieAddCounter = 0
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

while True: # Игровой цикл выполняется, пока игра работает.
    score += 1 # Увеличение количества очков.

for event in pygame.event.get():


if event.type == QUIT:terminate()
    reverseCheat = True
if event.key == K_x:
    slowCheat = True
if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
    moveRight = False
moveLeft = True
if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
    moveLeft = False
moveRight = True
if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
    moveDown = False
moveUp = True
if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
    moveUp = False
moveDown = True

if event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key == K_z:
        reverseCheat = False
score = 0
if event.key == K_x:
    slowCheat = False
score = 0
if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
    terminate()

if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
    moveLeft = False
if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
    moveRight = False
if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
    moveUp = False
if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
    moveDown = False

if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
    playerRect.centerx = event.pos[0]

playerRect.centery = event.pos[1]

if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
    baddieAddCounter += 1
if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
    baddieAddCounter = 0
baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                                }

baddies.append(newBaddie)

if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
    playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
                                                 playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
    playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
    playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)


for b in baddies:
 if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
  b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
reverseCheat: b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
slowCheat: b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

for b in baddies[:]:
 if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
    baddies.remove(b)

windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)


drawText('Счет: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
drawText('Рекорд: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

for b in baddies:
 windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

pygame.display.update()

if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    if score > topScore: topScore = score
exit()
mainClock.tick(FPS)

pygame.mixer.music.stop()
gameOverSound.play()

drawText('ИГРА ОКОНЧЕНА!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Нажмите клавишу для начала новой игры', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH /
3) - 120, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

gameOverSound.stop()
```

[image: не реaгирует на кнопки]

Comment: А у Вас реально так код отформатирован?

Comment: всмысле виктор?

Comment: Ну после if event.key == K_x: там столько отступов начинается в if конструкциях